# Error when trying to do a function in an OOP class

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I am using the "More Python Programming for Beginners" book and I am copying code from it.

I am trying to create a function to create text on the screen called `print_text()` with a bunch of arguments needed to render the text.

Here is the function:

```
def print_text(font, x, y, text, colour=(255, 255, 255), shadow=True):
    if shadow:
        txtimg = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
        surface.blit(txtimg, (x-2,y-2))
    txtimg = font.render(text, True, colour)
    surface.blit(txtimg, (x, y))
```

Here is the entire program:

```
# Trivia Game
#
# An editable quiz. Accumulate ALL the points.
# This has 11 questions so far.
#
# -------------------------------------------------

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

class Trivia(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        self.current = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.correct = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.scored = False
        self.failed = False
        self.wronganswer = 0
        self.colour = [white, white, white, white]

        txt = open("trivia.txt", "r")
        tdata = txt.readlines()
        txt.close()

        for text_line in tdata:
            self.data.append(text_line.strip())
            self.total += 1

    def print_text(font, x, y, text, colour=(255, 255, 255), shadow=True):
        if shadow:
            txtimg = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
            surface.blit(txtimg, (x-2,y-2))
        txtimg = font.render(text, True, colour)
        surface.blit(txtimg, (x, y))

    def show_question(self):
        trivia.print_text(font1, 210, 5, "TRIVIA GAME")
        print_text(font2, 192, 500-20, "press keys 1,2,3,4 to answer", blue)
        print_text(font2, 530, 5, "SCORE:", blue)
        print_text(font2, 550, 25, str(self.score), blue)

        self.correct = int(self.data[self.current+5])

        question = self.current // 6 + 1
        print_text(font1, 5, 80, "QUESTION " + str(question))
        print_text(font2, 20, 120, self.data[self.current], white)

        if self.scored:
            self.colour = [white, white, white, white]
            self.colour[self.correct-1] = green
            print_text(font1, 230, 380, "CORRECT!", green)
            print_text(font2, 170, 420, "Press Enter For Next Question", green)
        elif self.failed:
            self.colour = [white, white, white, white]
            self.colour[self.wronganswer-1] = red
            self.colour[self.correct-1] = green
            print_text(font1, 230, 380, "INCORRECT!", red)
            print_text(font2, 170, 420, "Press Enter For Next Question", red)

        print_text(font1, 5, 170, "ANSWERS")
        print_text(font2, 20, 210, "1 - " + self.data[self.current+1], self.colour[0])
        print_text(font2, 20, 240, "2 - " + self.data[self.current+2], self.colour[1])
        print_text(font2, 20, 270, "3 - " + self.data[self.current+3], self.colour[2])
        print_text(font2, 20, 300, "4 - " + self.data[self.current+4], self.colour[3])

    def handle_input(self,number):
        if not self.scored and not self.failed:
            if number == self.correct:
                self.scored = True
                self.score += 1
            else:
                self.failed = True
                self.wronganswer = number

    def next_question(self):
        if self.scored or self.failed:
            self.scored = False
            self.failed = False
            self.correct = 0
            self.colour = [white, white, white, white]
            self.current += 6
            if self.current >= self.total:
                self.current = 0

# main program

pygame.init()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("School")

font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

white = 255, 255, 255
blue = 0, 0, 255
green = 0, 255, 0
red = 255, 0, 0
black = 0, 0, 0

trivia = Trivia("trivia_data.txt")

# loop

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
                trivia.handle_input(1)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                trivia.handle_input(2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                trivia.handle_input(3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                trivia.handle_input(4)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                trivia.next_question()

    surface.fill((black))
    trivia.show_question()

    pygame.display.update()
```

The error I get while running this program is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PylonBuffering\Desktop\Pylon Buffering\Games\Other\Trivia Game\Trivia Game.pyw", line 126, in <module>
    trivia.show_question()
  File "C:\Users\PylonBuffering\Desktop\Pylon Buffering\Games\Other\Trivia Game\Trivia Game.pyw", line 39, in show_question
    trivia.print_text(font1, 210, 5, "TRIVIA GAME")
  File "C:\Users\PylonBuffering\Desktop\Pylon Buffering\Games\Other\Trivia Game\Trivia Game.pyw", line 33, in print_text
    txtimg = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
AttributeError: 'Trivia' object has no attribute 'render'
```

Help me. If you find this topic already solved, please link me to it.

Comment: print_text should have the first parameter self. This is added automatically to the parameter list when you call a method as an attribute of an object: trivia.print_text(...)->Trivia.print_text(trivia, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you doesn't have added the `self` parameter in `print_text`. If you call a method (as in "a function which belongs to a class") the first parameter passed into the function is always the instance itself, regardless of its name. So if you call `trivia.print_text(font1, ...)` the parameter `font` automatically becomes the value of `trivia` and `x` gets the value of `font1` and so on.

To verify it your self try this:

```
class Test:
    def func():
        print "test"

test = Test()
test.func()
```

This will raise:

```
TypeError: func() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

The argument `func` gets passed is the instance `test`. Python will "convert" `test.func()` to `Test.func(test)`.

Another problem is, that you are calling `print_text` from `show_question` without the self prefix. This way python will not find `print_text`, because the function isn't in the namespace.

You shouldn't call `trivia` from inside the class, instead use `self` (see `show_question` line 1).

So there three options:

- add `self` before `font` (dont't forget the instance (`self` or `trivia`) prefix before all `print_text` calls)
- move `print_text` out of the context of the class (remove all instance prefixes (`self` or `trivia`) before `print_text` calls)
- add the decorator [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to `print_text`, this prevents python from passing the instance as parameter (don't forget the instance (`self` or `trivia`) prefix before all `print_text` calls)

Comment: whoops -_- this book has screwed me over quite a few times, this has helped me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring the function `print_text` as a method of the `Trivia` class. What you actually need is to declare it in the global scope.

To solve this, move the `print_text` function out of the `Trivia` class from here:

```
        self.total += 1 # Do not move this line. I have only provided it for context

def print_text(font, x, y, text, colour=(255, 255, 255), shadow=True):
    if shadow:
        txtimg = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
        surface.blit(txtimg, (x-2,y-2))
    txtimg = font.render(text, True, colour)
    surface.blit(txtimg, (x, y))

def show_question(self): # Do not move this line. I have only provided it for context
```

... to here:

```
black = 0, 0, 0 # Do not move this line. I have only provided it for context

def print_text(font, x, y, text, colour=(255, 255, 255), shadow=True):
    if shadow:
        txtimg = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
        surface.blit(txtimg, (x-2,y-2))
    txtimg = font.render(text, True, colour)
    surface.blit(txtimg, (x, y))

trivia = Trivia("trivia_data.txt") # Do not move this line. I have only provided it for context
```